# Ansible - Fetching a file from a Windows remote share

Tags: windows, ansible, shared-directory

I'm trying to get a file from a windows DFS share to the localhost (linux) to parse it later.

The path to the file is something like : \\windows_host\folder\file

And I'm trying to use the fetch module with something similar to this:

`- name: Test
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
tasks:
    - name: Fetching a file from a Windows DFS Share
      fetch:
         src: \\windows_host\folder\file
         dest: local_folder/file
         flat: yes`

But when I run it, it does not get the file and if I use the verbose option it says:
**"msg": "the remote file does not exist, not transferring, ignored"**

Though the file exists at the specific location.. so I think the problem is with the path encoding (I might be wrong) and I have tried a few different formats but so far no luck.

Does anyone know how to do that or what I'm doing wrong?

Alternative ways to get the file are also appreciated considering anyway that
I'm not allowed to mount the share or to have any service (ftp/http/etc..)  returning the file

Thanks in advance

ValerioG

Comment: Where did you find information, that `fetch` module will work with UNC shares?

Comment: Honestly I did not find anything specific to UNC shares.. 
I googled for how to copy a file from Windows and this seems to be the most common option so I'm just testing it..
Is there another module/approach afayk?

Answer (score 3):

I actually managed to make it work using the command module and smbclient command in linux.
In case someone needs something similar, the playbook below works for me.

```html
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - vault_with_AD_credentials.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: Getting the Exchange Data file from Windows Share
      run_once: yes
      command: smbclient '\\windows_host\share' -c 'lcd local_folder; cd remote_folder; get filename' -U {{ ad_username }}%{{ ad_password }}
```